# How can I perform LiveData transformations on a background thread?

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-thread, android-architecture-lifecycle

I have a need to transform one type of data, returned by a `LiveData` object, into another form **on a background thread** to prevent UI lag.

In my specific case, I have:

- `MyDBRow` objects (POJOs consisting of primitive `long`s and `String`s);
- a [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) [DAO](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data.html) instance emitting these via a `LiveData<List<MyDBRow>>`; and
- a UI expecting richer `MyRichObject` objects (POJOs with the primitives inflated into e.g. [date/time objects](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/index.html))

so I need to transform my `LiveData<List<MyDBRow>>` into a `LiveData<List<MyRichObject>>`, but **not on the UI thread**.

The [`Transformations.map(LiveData<X>, Function<X, Y>)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations.html#map(android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData%3CX%3E,%20android.arch.core.util.Function%3CX,%20Y%3E)) method does this needed transformation, but I can't use this because it **executes the transformation on the main thread**:

> Applies the given function on the main thread to each value emitted by `source` LiveData and returns LiveData, which emits resulting values.
>
> The given function `func` will be executed on the main thread.

What is a clean way to make `LiveData` transformations occur:

1. somewhere off the main thread, and
2. only as needed (i.e. only when something is observing the intended transformation)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- The original, “source” [`LiveData`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html) can be monitored by a new [`Observer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Observer.html) instance.
- This `Observer` instance, when source `LiveData` is emitted, can prepare a background thread to perform the needed transformation and then emit it via a new, “transformed” `LiveData`.
- The transformed `LiveData` can attach the aforementioned `Observer` to the source `LiveData` when it has active `Observer`s, and detach them when it doesn't, ensuring that the source `LiveData` is only being observed when necessary.

The question gives an example source `LiveData<List<MyDBRow>>` and needs a transformed `LiveData<List<MyRichObject>>`.  A combined transformed `LiveData` and `Observer` could look something like this:

```
class MyRichObjectLiveData
        extends LiveData<List<MyRichObject>>
        implements Observer<List<MyDBRow>>
{
    @NonNull private LiveData<List<MyDBRow>> sourceLiveData;

    MyRichObjectLiveData(@NonNull LiveData<List<MyDBRow>> sourceLiveData) {
        this.sourceLiveData = sourceLiveData;
    }

    // only watch the source LiveData when something is observing this
    // transformed LiveData
    @Override protected void onActive()   { sourceLiveData.observeForever(this); }
    @Override protected void onInactive() { sourceLiveData.removeObserver(this); }

    // receive source LiveData emission
    @Override public void onChanged(@Nullable List<MyDBRow> dbRows) {
        // set up a background thread to complete the transformation
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                assert dbRows != null;
                List<MyRichObject> myRichObjects = new LinkedList<>();
                for (MyDBRow myDBRow : myDBRows) {
                    myRichObjects.add(MyRichObjectBuilder.from(myDBRow).build());
                }
                // use LiveData method postValue (rather than setValue) on
                // background threads
                postValue(myRichObjects);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If multiple such transformations are needed, the above logic could be made generic like this:

```
abstract class TransformedLiveData<Source, Transformed>
        extends LiveData<Transformed>
        implements Observer<Source>
{
    @Override protected void onActive()   { getSource().observeForever(this); }
    @Override protected void onInactive() { getSource().removeObserver(this); }

    @Override public void onChanged(@Nullable Source source) {
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                postValue(getTransformed(source));
            }
        });
    }

    protected abstract LiveData<Source> getSource();
    protected abstract Transformed getTransformed(Source source);
}
```

and the subclass for the example given by the question could look something like this:

```
class MyRichObjectLiveData
        extends TransformedLiveData<List<MyDBRow>, List<MyRichObject>>
{
    @NonNull private LiveData<List<MyDBRow>> sourceLiveData;

    MyRichObjectLiveData(@NonNull LiveData<List<MyDBRow>> sourceLiveData) {
        this.sourceLiveData = sourceLiveData;
    }

    @Override protected LiveData<List<MyDBRow>> getSource() {
        return sourceLiveData;
    }

    @Override protected List<MyRichObject> getTransformed(List<MyDBRow> myDBRows) {
        List<MyRichObject> myRichObjects = new LinkedList<>();
        for (MyDBRow myDBRow : myDBRows) {
            myRichObjects.add(MyRichObjectBuilder.from(myDBRow).build());
        }
        return myRichObjects;
    }
}
```

Comment: The downside of this solution, @Alex Peters, is that it always goes through the main thread. Unfortunately, LiveData doesn't have the possibility to change on which thread to run the result, unlike ReactiveX which does.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand.  Are you saying that the `Runnable` passed to `AsyncTask.execute` is still going to run on the main thread?  I'm not worried about any code outside the `Runnable` running on the main thread, as everything outside that `Runnable` is comparatively very lightweight.

Comment: Ohh, I see—ReactiveX gives you things like `observeOn` and `subscribeOn`, which allow you to decide in one line which thread (or pool of threads!) your computations will run on.  Very neat, and it would render most of my code above moot.

Comment: AdyncTask...???? OMG!!! Google says to avoid using it....

Comment: Thanks @james04.  What's your recommended alternative?

Answer (score 11):

It may be eaiser to do using `MediatorLiveData`. `Transformations.map()` is implemented with `MediatorLiveData` under the hood.

```java
@MainThread
public static <X, Y> LiveData<Y> mapAsync(
  @NonNull LiveData<X> source,
  @NonNull final Function<X, Y> mapFunction) {
  final MediatorLiveData<Y> result = new MediatorLiveData<>();
  result.addSource(source, new Observer<X>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable final X x) {
      AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          result.postValue(mapFunction.apply(x));
        }
      });
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Could you please give a sample implementation of `mapFunction`?

Answer (score 9):

Listen to a `MediatorLiveData<T>` that listens to two other `LiveData<T>`s.

For example:

```
val exposed: LiveData<List<T>> = MediatorLiveData<List<T>>().apply {
    addSource(aLiveDataToMap) { doWorkOnAnotherThread(it) }
    addSource(aMutableLiveData) { value = it }
}

private fun doWorkOnAnotherThread(t: T) {
    runWorkOnAnotherThread {
        val t2 = /* ... */
        aMutableLiveData.postValue(t2)
    }
}
```

Whenever `aLiveDataToMap` changes, it will trigger `doWorkOnAnotherThread()` which will then set the value of `aMutableLiveData`, which finally sets to value of `exposed`, which a lifecycle-owner will be listening to. Replace `T`s with your desired type.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @jaychang0917

Kotlin Form :

```
@MainThread
fun <X, Y> mapAsync(source: LiveData<X>, mapFunction: androidx.arch.core.util.Function<X, Y>): LiveData<Y> {
    val result = MediatorLiveData<Y>()
    result.addSource(source) { x -> AsyncTask.execute { result.postValue(mapFunction.apply(x)) } }
    return result
}
```

Comment: This one works, but I would have preferred using Executor instead of AsyncTask.

Comment: Why so many people are still using AsynTasks, Executors and other low level multithreading techniques when there are Rx and Coroutines? 
Would appreciate if someone explains the reason behind this.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with coroutines:

```
class RichLiveData(val rows: LiveData<List<MyDBRow>>) : LiveData<List<MyRichObject>>(),
        CoroutineScope by CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default) {

    private val observer = Observer<List<MyDBRow>> { rows ->
        launch {
            postValue(/*computationally expensive stuff which returns a List<MyRichObject>*/)
        }
    }

    override fun onActive() {
        rows.observeForever(observer)
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        rows.removeObserver(observer)
    }
}
```

Comment: No, because it runs with `Dispatches.Default` which is designed for computationally demanding code.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution with coroutines:

```
object BackgroundTransformations {

    fun <X, Y> map(
        source: LiveData<X>,
        mapFunction: (X) -> Y
    ): LiveData<Y> {
        val result = MediatorLiveData<Y>()

        result.addSource(source, Observer<X> { x ->
            if (x == null) return@Observer
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
                result.postValue(mapFunction(x))
            }
        })

        return result
    }

    fun <X, Y> switchMap(
        source: LiveData<X>,
        switchMapFunction: (X) -> LiveData<Y>
    ): LiveData<Y> {
        val result = MediatorLiveData<Y>()
        result.addSource(source, object : Observer<X> {
            var mSource: LiveData<Y>? = null

            override fun onChanged(x: X) {
                if (x == null) return

                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
                    val newLiveData = switchMapFunction(x)
                    if (mSource == newLiveData) {
                        return@launch
                    }
                    if (mSource != null) {
                        result.removeSource(mSource!!)
                    }
                    mSource = newLiveData
                    if (mSource != null) {
                        result.addSource(mSource!!) { y ->
                            result.setValue(y)
                        }
                   }
                }
            }
        })
        return result
    }

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: `IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke observeForever on a background thread`

Answer (score 0):

How about like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM " + PeriodicElement.TABLE_NAME)
abstract fun getAll(): LiveData<List<PeriodicElement>>

fun getAllElements(): LiveData<HashMap<String, PeriodicElement>> {
    return Transformations.switchMap(getAll(), ::transform)
}

private fun transform(list: List<PeriodicElement>): LiveData<HashMap<String, PeriodicElement>> {
    val map = HashMap<String, PeriodicElement>()
    val liveData = MutableLiveData(map)

    AsyncTask.execute {
        for (p in list) {
            map[p.symbol] = p

            if (!liveData.hasObservers()) {
                //prevent memory leak
                break
            }
        }
        liveData.postValue(map)
    }
    return liveData
}
```